# Can you store the output of a query in a Global variable in Oracle SQL developer?

Tags: sql, global-variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that returns a single date and I want to store this date in a global variable so that it can be used elsewhere.
Below is the query that returns a single date:

```
select distinct
    case when to_char(batchdate, 'd') between 1 and 6 then batchdate - to_char(batchdate, 'd') else  batchdate end edate
from table
where batchdate = (select max(batchdate) from table);
```

Now I am trying to use an in-built function called `DEFINE` to declare a global variable.

```
DEFINE = (select distinct
    case when to_char(batchdate, 'd') between 1 and 6 then batchdate - to_char(batchdate, 'd') else  batchdate end edate
from table
where batchdate = (select max(batchdate) from table))
```

> This throws an error.

Is there any way in which I can store the output of this query in a global variable?

Comment: correction : DEFINE edate = <the query>

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes - kind of. Here's an example which contains list of statements you'd put into SQL Developer:

```
variable v_max_sal number;

exec select max(sal) into :v_max_sal from emp;

select ename from emp where sal = :v_max_sal;
```

If you execute them one-by-one, it'll be OK until the last one which will prompt you for `:v_max_sal` variable's value (and that's not what you want). But, if you execute the last statement (or - when we're at it - the whole code) as a **script** (`F9` keyboard shortcut key in latest versions), then you'll get the final result as expected.

See if it helps.

**[EDIT]**

As of your example: I tried it, works OK for me. Here's a sample table:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From tablea;

BATCHDATE
----------
01.11.2019

SQL>
```

These are lines I ran in my SQL Developer (version 18.3) by pressing F9:

```
var edate varchar2(20);

exec select distinct case when to_char(max(batchdate), 'd') between 1 and 6 then max(batchdate) - to_char(max(batchdate), 'd') else max(batchdate) end into :edate from tablea; 

select * from tablea where batchdate <> to_date(:edate);
```

The `exec` line **has to be that long**, you can't split it into several lines so that it is nicely formatted (at least, I think so - I couldn't make it work otherwise).

The final result was (copied from the "Script Output" window):

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


BATCHDATE 
----------
01/11/2019
```

I wasn't prompted for anything, so ... it works for me. I don't know why it does not for you. Which SQL Developer version do you use?

Comment: Thank you!Here's what I am trying now. 

var edate varchar2(20);

exec select distinct case when to_char(max(batchdate), 'd') between 1 and 6 then max(batchdate) - to_char(max(batchdate), 'd') else  max(batchdate) end into :edate from table;

select * from table
where batchdate = to_date(:edate);

The first two scripts ran perfectly and like you said, running it individually prompted me to enter the edate value after the last query is run, but i get the same when i F9 the entire thing.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer; have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! the result for "Script Output" is obtained by pressing F5 in my SQL developer. My final table is huge and it's not feasible for me to view the output as a script. I want to export it as an Excel for further analysis too. To get the result directly in grid view I used DEFINE sdate = to_date(:edate) and then use sdate in getting the final table select * from table where batchdate = &sdate; This is not working. Is there a way to get the result in Grid view instead of Script Output.

Comment: I don't think so. Consider switching to PL/SQL. In there, you can store result of the first query into a local variable and use it later to create the output file. You'd use `UTL_FILE` package to do that. But, in SQL layer ... as I said, I think you can't do what you want **unless** you switch to SQL*Plus (instead of SQL Developer). There you can use its `spool` command to get the result. It won't be an Excel file for sure, but - it can be a CSV which is then easily opened by Excel.

Comment: Okay.. The client support is available only on SQL Dev so can't move elsewhere. THank you so much for your answers though. Really appreciate it.